# Command prompt New Item not working

Tags: command, gruntjs, command-prompt

I am following this [tutorial for GruntJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGMmkQEJZxU) and at the 1min 40sec mark the command `new-item` is used but when I do it on my command propmpt i get the following error

```
'new-item' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think it is an alias that he created to create a new file. `touch`will work too.

Comment: I had tried touch too but it didnt work for me :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new-item` is a powershell command and will only work if you're using powershell, like the person is in the video. It is a command for creating a new file or folder: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx

The equivalent in bash would be `touch readme.md` to create a readme.md file, such as if you're on OSX.

Or if you're using Windows cmd.exe, `call>readme.md`.

Or just create a file named `readme.md` with your GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just creating one. People doing the tutorials should point that sort of thing out. Its not many advanced people that are going to be watching a tutorial to learn

Comment: fyi, the official docs don't even tell you to use powershell. They even have a step above for "if you are using cmd...", so you would think they would mention this part. Official steps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/#install-on-windows-using-chocolatey-or-scoop